# Select Element by part of the name jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, sharepoint

I need to check if the checkbox is checked, the thing is the check box has name and id and I can't use them as it is a sharepoint site and both name and id could be changed once a new element introduced to the page.
What should I do?

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="190px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
    <nobr>All employees in department</nobr>
</h3></td>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <!-- FieldName="All employees"
         FieldInternalName="All_x0020_employees_x0020_in_x00"
         FieldType="SPFieldBoolean"
      --> 
 <span dir="none">
    <input id="ctl00_m_g_49618ec6_4999_44aa_87e7_6087a1cf4a6f_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_BooleanField" 
    type="checkbox" name="ctl00$m$g_49618ec6_4999_44aa_87e7_6087a1cf4a6f$ctl00$ctl05$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$BooleanField" /><br />
</span>
        select employees !

    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript's [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and a CSS selector, like this

```
if (document.querySelector('input').checked) {
  // checked, so do something
}
```

---

And if you only want the `input` in the `td` with class `ms-formbody`, like this

```
if (document.querySelector('td.ms-formbody input').checked) {
  // checked, so do something
}
```

---

Additionally, if you know e.g. the beginning of the `name` will always be the same, you can use the *start with* attribute selector `[attribute^="value"]`

```
if (document.querySelector('input[name^="ct100"]').checked) {
  // checked, so do something
}
```

or if the end of the `name` will, use the *end with* attribute selector `[attribute$="value"]`

```
if (document.querySelector('input[name$="BooleanField"]').checked) {
  // checked, so do something
}
```

---

For jQuery, use its [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method combined with any of the above selectors

```
if ($( "selector" ).prop("checked")) {
  // checked, so do something
}
```

Comment: In this case it is the end of the name that does not change. what should I user instead of [name^?

Comment: @dolly_do Then you do `'input[name$="BooleanField"]'` ... updated my answer with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery selector when the attribute starts from some string

```
$( "input[name^='ctl00']" ).is( ":checked" )
```